# links in labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, label

I am using this code to place a link for each label:

```
  chart2.addAxis("y", {
        vertical: true, 
        fixLower: "none", 
        fixUpper: "none", 
        natural: true,
        majorTick: { length: 3 },
           labels: [{value: 1, text: <a href="url">Link text</a> }, ...]
    });
```

Apparently this code didn't work. So, i am thinking:
I have this html in the rendered chart:

```
<div id="chart2" style="height: 100px;">
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; ...">
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; ... ">Link&nbsp;text</div> //label
</div>
...
```

And this change should result:

```
Link&nbsp;text
```

to something like:

```
<a href="url">Link&nbsp;text</a>
```

How can i do this change with jquery or dojo ? Basically add `<a href="url">` before and `</a>` after the text.

Comment: Well, you're missing the quotes. Does it work *with* the quotes?

Comment: @minitech sorry, what quotes are you talking about ?

Comment: `text: <a href="url">Link text</a>`. It should be: `text: '<a href="url">Link text</a>'`.

Comment: @minitech will output this html code: `<a&nbsp;href="url">Link&nbsp;text</a&nbsp;href="url">`

Comment: So... is this jQuery or is it Dojo?

Comment: @minitech The code above is dojo. Basically the labels are a json response. But i am using dojo and jquery, so the solution (change the label) can be dojo or jquery.